# Whipped cream running permanently from siphon

Tags: whipped-cream

I have a Kayser siphon of whipped cream. I filled it with whipped cream (not fully though), added some sugar and swung it. It works perfectly, only today it wouldn't stop. But once Ive used, it won't stop flowing grom the siphon even though i stopped using it.

Comment: Sounds like something's got stuck in the valve. Give it a couple of good presses and maybe that'll clear it.

Answer (score 1):

your gasket is probably not clean enough. try taking it apart and giving everything a thorough cleaning and it should work again.